# Writing to pipe or pipes

Tags: c, unix, named-pipes

What is the best way to do this theoretically? I need to let the user enter the number of processes to send to a pipe for instance "3" and as it loops through the three *[three whats?]* on each iteration I need to create a process, send it *[what?]* to the pipe and print it.

The next time the user enters another number, say "4", it should print the previous 3 + 1.. I am working on this but can't understand how do it. Here is my code. I just need guidance, no need to try to solve it for me (but suggestions would be much appreciated).

Right now I am able to send one through the pipe and return it but then the pipe closes and it does not allow for the other processes to get in there.

Comment: Your explanation of what you want to do is, as yet, unclear.  Please express your requirements more carefully.

Comment: What's the output of the program supposed to look like if it's working? And why are you using named pipes? They seem a poor choice if the number of pipes you're going to have is dynamic, as the problem statement appears to suggest.

Comment: Added the homework tag. Feel free to remove it if it is not homework after all.

Comment: yeah it part of a homework, i am stuck, it should display what i wrote there in the program "This process is...". Also, i need to use named pipes as in the previous we used the unnamed. So basically if i enter "3" it should print the three process ids that we passed to the pipe or pipes

Comment: @user975582: Your explanation of what the output is supposed to look like isn't particularly helpful. Please edit your original question and put in a section showing a specific and complete example of what the output would look like if the program ran properly.

Comment: Your client is not a Full Duplex client; it is strictly synchronous and Half Duplex.

Comment: At the moment, the server.c code is irrelevant as the client.c code does not use it.  You really need to start with a clear statement of what is required - it is really hard to create good code when you don't understand what you are trying to produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggestion #1: Use functions

Use functions, even for little jobs such as:

```
void create_fifo(const char *name)
{
    /* Create the first named - pipe */
    int ret_val = mkfifo(name, 0666);

    if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST))
    {
        perror("Error creating the named pipe");
        exit(1);
    } 
}
```

Now you can simply write in your main program:

```
create_fifo(PIPE1);
create_fifo(PIPE5);
```

This cuts down on the clutter in your main program.  It also adheres to the Agile principle DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

#### Suggestion #2: Error check system calls.

You did that for creating the FIFOs, which is good.  You don't for the `open()` calls, or the `read()` or `write()` calls.  You probably should.  I use a function similar to the following in my programs:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static const char *arg0 = "did not call err_setarg0(argv[0])";

void err_setarg0(const char *argv0)
{
    arg0 = argv0;
}

void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;   /* Capture errno before it is changed */
    va_lists args;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", arg0);
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}
```

You can then use:

```
if ((rdfd1 = open(PIPE1, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    err_exit("Failed to open FIFO %s for reading: ", PIPE1);
if ((wrfd1 = open(PIPE5, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
    err_exit("Failed to open FIFO %s for writing: ", PIPE5);
```

#### Suggestion #3: Make an iterative server

Your server program currently opens the FIFOs once, then reads from one, write to the other, and terminates.  You need a loop around some portion of this code, maybe two nested loops.  You have to decide whether you need an inner loop to read until EOF.  You also need to know how you will terminate the server.

#### Suggestion #4: Maybe the server needs pipe names as arguments

Your server currently works on fixed FIFO names.  You probably need it to take input and output file names as command line arguments, so that when your client spawns multiple servers, each server can have its own set of FIFOs, rather than all processes sharing the same two FIFOs, which is going to lead to confusion and chaos.

Indeed, the need for generating names calls the whole design into question - are you sure using FIFOs is the best way to do this?  It looks to me like a case where anonymous pipes would serve you better; you wouldn't have to invent names, and the server would simply read from its standard input and write the (modified?) data to its standard output, so you could even simply use `cat` or `tr` or `sed` or ... as your server.

Clearly, if you use pipes, you will need to do some careful plumbing, but you also need to do careful plumbing with the pairs of FIFOs per server.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will follow your guideline, but still it does not answer how i can pass multiple processes to a pipe or pipes and print them in the client side...

Comment: the loop would be in the server side or in the client side?

Comment: Also, how can i keep the pipe open to keep receiving requests?

Comment: I would also suggest he use arrays instead of var1, var2, var3, var4

Comment: @Dave: yes, I absolutely agree on arrays instead repeated varN.  The code might benefit from a small structure to bundle the two file descriptors, maybe the two pipe names, and the buffer into one convenient unit - and then it can use an array of these structures.  And functions to manipulate aspects of these structures.

Comment: I have to used named pipes :(

Comment: You cannot 'pass multiple processes to a pipe'; the concept of passing a process to a pipe is simply ... well, you can't do it.  I'm not sure if this is an 'English as a Second Language' problem or a fundamental misunderstanding or both.  The loop(s) would be in the server code, as indicated by the heading 'make an iterative server'.  However, since the client program doesn't use the server, that advice is arguably pointless.

Comment: You can have multiple processes with a single FIFO open for writing. Once all the writers have closed the FIFO, the reader will get EOF (0 bytes read).  At that point, the reader should close the FIFO and reopen it, which will hang until there is a writer that opens the FIFO.  It can then go into a loop (again) and read whatever comes in, writing it wherever you want it to go.  I saw the requirement to use FIFOs; that's why I asked "are you sure?". The requirement is bogus, a typical 'use the wrong tool for the job because it is a learning exercise on how to use the specific tool'.

Comment: Oh well thanks for trying everyone... i will give you the answer although i am still stuck. Thanks

Comment: All i want is to create three process ids, send those to the pipe and then print them in the client... I added the desired output

Comment: Do you have to create three processes to get the PIDs, or can you simply use 1, 2 and 3 as PIDs?  If you have to create processes, is it the parent or the child that must do the writing?  The parent is told its child PID, so it doesn't need the child to tell it.  Your requirements are still unclear.  Why you need the server code is still unclear.

Comment: Ok how can i do this without the server code?, if i dont need it.. And yes the parent should do the writing.. So the User enters "3" so the program should create 3 processes and then use the pipe to print them